# Prove that $f\in L^p[0,1]$ for all $p\in[1,2)$:

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Given that $f:[0,1]\to[0,\infty)$ in $L^1$ such that $\int_E f$ $dm\leq\sqrt{m(E)}$ for every $E\subseteq[0,1]$ measurable, prove that $f\in L^p[0,1]$ for all $p\in[1,2)$.

This is a qualifying preparation exam question. None of us have seen anything with $L^p$ spaces before and so have no real idea how to get started. Hints? Suggestions? Proofs? Many thanks.

Comment: Try dealing with sets $E$ that are of some form $\left\{\left|f\right|>c\right\}$ (or its complement), where $c>0$.

Comment: How could you possibly be taking analysis quals and never "have seen anything with $L_p$ spaces before"?

Comment: @DavidMitra It was the professor's first year teaching and spent far too long on the easier material. We also may have learned about $L^p$ spaces without calling them that. I just know that we completely skipped the chapter entitled "$L^P$ Spaces" in our text.

Comment: This should work: let $E_c=[f>c]$. Then $\int_{E_c} f\ge c m(E_c)$. From your hypothesis, we then have $m(E_c)\le 1/c^2$. So then $m[ f^p> c]=m[f>c^{1/p}]\le 1/c^{2/p}$. Now use the equality $\int_{E_1} f^p =\int_1^\infty m[f^p> c]\,dc$.